# Apache rewriting rules erasing global $_SERVER['request-uri']

Tags: php, docker, mod-rewrite

I'm currently maintaining a legacy application that is running locally in a server. I created a Dockerfile with the same specifications with this server but I'm getting an odd error. 
This legacy app was built with the own home-made framework the old programmer developed. And he seriously relies in the value of the global $_SERVER['request_uri'] for routing.

In the server the value is the requested uri (ie www.test.local), in the docker version I get just "/" as a response. Here is my docker-compose

```
#-- v2 syntax
version: '2'

# Named volumes
volumes:
# MySQL Data
  hibrida-mysql-data:
  driver: local

  services:
   # MySQL (5.7)
   mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: hibrida-mysql
   volumes:
    - ./.db-data/:/var/lib/mysql
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=hibrida    
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=hibrida
  - MYSQL_USER=hibrida
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=hibrida

# PHP (with Nginx)
app:
image: 1and1internet/ubuntu-16-apache-php-5.6
container_name: hibrida-apache
environment:
  XDEBUG_ENABLED: "true"
  XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=192.168.25.3"
  PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=dev.local"
volumes:
  - ./public:/var/www
  - ./config/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/vhost.conf
  - ./config/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vhost.conf
  #- ./config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
  #- ./config/www.conf:/etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf

ports:
  - "80:80"
links:
  - mysql
```

I just logged into the apache container and I switched on ae2nmod rewrite. What could it be?

Comment: Could it be something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200070/serverrequest-uri-returns-full-url-instead-of-path-to-script ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is the one of the most reliable ways to see the original, unmodified request from the client, and reflects the first line of the HTTP request, regardless of how the PHP script was invoked. It should not contain the hostname, and `/` is to be expected when visiting the document root. Something else is modifying it.